# Why should Q not exceed 1/2 on a 2-stage filter?

Tags: filter

I am just starting on filters.

I've seen on a tutorial that says 2-stage RC filter Q could not exceed 1/2. Could someone give some explanation?

Comment: [Related](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13132/realisation-of-a-passive-rc-low-pass-filter) but not an exact answer.

Answer (score 5):

First, I assume there is a buffer amplifier between two low-pass RC networks so that the two do not interact.  In that case, the overall transfer function is simply the product of the two 1st order LPF transfer functions:

$$\frac{V_o}{V_i} = \frac{1}{1 + sR_1C_1} \frac{1}{1 + sR_2C_2} = \frac{1}{1 + s\left(R_1C_1 + R_2C_2 \right) + s^2R_1C_1R_2C_2}$$

The standard form for a 2nd order LPF transfer function is

$$H(s) = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{Q}\frac{s}{s_0} + \frac{s^2}{s^2_0}}$$

Now we can identify

$$s_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{R_1C_1R_2C_2}}$$

$$Q = \frac{\sqrt{R_1C_1R_2C_2}}{R_1C_1 + R_2C_2}$$

which has a *maximum* value of \$\frac{1}{2}\$ when \$R_1C_1 = R_2C_2\$

At a deeper level, we can write the product of two 1st order LPF transfer functions as so:

$$H(s) = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{s}{s_1}} \frac{1}{1 + \frac{s}{s_2}} = \frac{1}{1 + s\left(\frac{1}{s_1} + \frac{1}{s_2}\right) + \frac{s^2}{s_1s_2}}$$

thus

$$s_0 = \sqrt{s_1s_2}$$

and

$$Q = \frac{\sqrt{s_1s_2}}{s_1 + s_2}$$

If \$s_1\$ and \$s_2\$ are real then \$Q\le\frac{1}{2}\$.  *However*, if \$s_1 = s_0\$ and \$s_2 = s^*_0\$ are complex conjugates then

$$Q = \frac{|s_0|}{2\Re(s_0)}$$

which can be larger than \$\frac{1}{2}\$

Comment: I am talking about the case when there is no buffer amplifier. But now I see that it would be even lower than 0.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without going deeper into system theory the most simple explanation is that for Q values larger than 0.5 we need either a resonant effect (impossible with R and C only) or an amplifier with frequency-dependent positive feedback. In both cases, complex poles are created, which is NOT possible using passive RC circuits only.

As another answer we must remember that the quality factor Q of a filter is identical to the "pole quality" of the corresponding complex pole pair with **Q=Qp=1/2cos(phi)**. Here the angle phi is defined between the negative-real axis of the complex s-plane and the vector to the pole. Because passive RC circuits can produce only poles which are real the angle phi is zero and the equation above reduces to **Q=Qp=1/2cos(0)=0.5.**

Comment: I agree with you. RC could not form a resonant tank or make complex poles. Another question, for the active 2nd order filter, is there any short cut to get transfer function? or we can only use KCL KVL or mason equation to get it?

Comment: Right - you must apply the classical rules and equations for analyzing linear circuits (KVL, KCL and formulas derived from it).